# Метапроверка не должна содержать русскоязычного кода

Tags: предложение, очередь-проверок

Наткнулся на метапроверку (проверку проверяющего) в очереди проверок. Она вычисляется слишком уж просто, т.к. в код врезаны слова на русском языке.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Думаю, это слишком уж просто. Нужно, чтобы нарезался только англоязычный код.

Comment: Вроде туда реальные вопросы включаются?

Comment: @Qwertiy да, вопрос там реальный использован. Проблема с тем, что "робо-вандализм" на русском языке. Вероятно, исходный алгоритм спокойно нарезает любой текст и на англоязычных сайтах это работает нормально. А вот на не-англоязычных эффективность такого примера снижается. У японцев даже ещё ярче будет.

Comment: Надо просто набрать нормальных вопросов с кодом на русском :)

Answer (score 2):

Будем откровенны: в число необходимых условий, чтобы прозевать робо-вандализм, входят два литра водки, близорукость в двадцать диоптрий, врождённая неграмотность, отравление сильнодействующими наркотическими веществами и лишняя хромосома — даже если вы делаете проверку на языке, который не понимаете. Единственное, что этот тест проверяет — это что юзер вообще читает, что принимает.

Тест-то улучшить можно, но было бы неплохо, если бы авторы довели коверкание сообщений до сколь-нибудь правдоподобного вида хотя бы на английском. Пока что я не наблюдаю подвижек даже в этом направлении.

Comment: В целом согласен, но шутка про хромосому некорректна.